# Sent Twitter tweet

Tags: android, twitter, oauth-2.0

I want to sent twitter tweet from android device

Actually. I am making an app from where the user can post their ideas to all main social networks (like Facebook, Gowalla, Twitter, Foursquare etc.) using Oauth2.

Comment: That's great. What have you tried?

Comment: Try Twitter4J (http://twitter4j.org/en/index.html).

Comment: That's OK, we all sometimes do. Just send it.

Comment: My answer includes a link to a tutorial about using Oauth with Twitter.

Comment: In fairness to everyone, theres no need to edit your question because you aren't happy with one answer as the rest of the answers actually go some way to try and help. Also, when you clicked on the ask a question button it gave you a FAQ to read about asking questions; http://stackoverflow.com/faq which if you read through, you wouldn't ask a question of "I want to sent twitter tweet from android device". Don't take anything to heart, just start out with a more elaborate question and focus on the helpful answers. If you don't get good answers, its because you asked a poor question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you don't mean that generically (open the Twitter app or visit www.twitter.com in the Android browser and send your Tweet)...

If you meant it programmatically, you can use Twitter's REST API: http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554679/Twitter-API-Documentation

Answer (score 0):

http://apiwiki.twitter.com/w/page/22554648/FrontPage <--- API's to interact with Twitter
and
http://abhinavasblog.blogspot.com/2010/09/using-twitter-with-oauth-on-andorid.html <-- More specific examples

Otherwise. This is generally a bad question. Infact its not even a question really, more of a statement.
Please edit to be more specific (to ask a question etc)

Answer (score -2):

Go to [www.twitter.com](http://www.twitter.com) and send it. Android phones come with a built in web browser enabling you to do this.